# NullPointerException when running JNLP in Java Web Start (jar works as stardardlone)

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, embedded-resource, jnlp

I wrote my first application and I sill can't fix one issue.
When running application using Eclipse - everything works ok.
After export to runnable jar (using Export required libraries into generated JAR), when running jar in Windows - everything works ok.

When I'm trying to run application using jnlp file and Java Web Start - it throws:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException    
   at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at MedicalOffice.MedicalOfficeView.<init>(MedicalOfficeView.java:122)
```

The point is that following code:

```
imgURL = MedicalOfficeView.class.getResource("/patientsListSmall.jpg");
patientsList.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgURL));
```

throws NullPointerException.

I have image folder in my project, added it to classpath and used the code above. It works only in Eclipse and standardlone jar file. I checked jar file and image exists in main jar folder.

This is my jnlp code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codbase="http://localhost:8081/MOS/"
href="MedicalOfficeSoftware.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Small Medical Office Management Software</title>
        <vendor>Pawel Raczy</vendor>
        <description>MedicalOfficeManagement</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+"/>
        <jar href="MedicalOfficeSoftware.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="MedicalOffice.MVCMedicalOffice"/> 
</jnlp>
```

I also tried to use following code in my application:

```
URL imgURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("patientsListSmall.jpg");
patientsList.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgURL));
```

as well as this one:

```
URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("patientsListSmall.jpg");
patientsList.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgURL));
```

Effect is the same - works only in eclipse and standardlone jar file.

Comment: *"I have image folder in my project,.."*  Is that directory and its content being included in `MedicalOfficeSoftware.jar`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, after adding this folder to classpath, it's extracted to main jar content (jpg file is directly in MedicalOfficeSoftware.jar file).
I tried to use getClass().getClassLoader().getResource which is searching directly in classpath, so i don't understand why it throws NullPointerException (only when using jnlp file - jar is still working perfectly without it).
If my runnable jar file will also throw NullPointerException, I would probably know how to fix it, but it throws this exception only when using jnlp and Java Web Start. Does it change anything in java mechanic?

Comment: OK.. instead of `"addPatientSmall.jpg"` try `"/addPatientSmall.jpg"` (note leading `/`).  The `/` explicitly tells the JRE to look in the 'root' of the class-path.  **Edit:** I just noticed you *mentioned trying both.*  Stick with the leading `/` only, is my recommendation.

Comment: What is the resulting `URL` in each of your attempts?  I have a feeling you need to create your image `resourcePath` to a URL with `classLoader.findResource(resourcePath).toExternalForm()`.  I have some working, production code that does that very thing.  It it must be there fore a reason.

Comment: After creating URL, it is printing something like this:
file:/C:/Java/Git/MedicalOfficeManagementSoftware/SmallMedicalOfficeManagement/bin/addPatientSmall.jpg
Hmm getResource() method invokes findResource() by default and toExternalForm is just returning string from URL.

I don't know too much about creating  custom classLoaders. I have to read a bit more about it. Then i'll write what the result is.

Answer (score -1):

Does your signed jar has the Trusted-Library attribute in the manifest file?